# rank smallest to largest

Tags: t-sql, rank, sql-server-2017

I have the following sample data:

```
declare @table table
(
    Tbl             char(2)
,   TxDate          date
,   AutoIdx         int
,   Debit           float
,   Credit          float
,   Order_No        varchar(50)
,   ExtOrderNum     varchar(50)
,   Reference       varchar(50)
,   Reference2      varchar(50)
,   Description     varchar(100)
,   AuditNumber     varchar(50)
)

insert into @table
(
    Tbl
,   TxDate
,   AutoIdx
,   Debit
,   Credit
,   Order_No
,   ExtOrderNum
,   Reference
,   Reference2
,   Description
,   AuditNumber
)
values
    ('GL','2020-03-18',877224,0,2306.9,'PO07673','blue/Prov','60','GRV8399','Purchase Order','26382.0001')
,   ('AP','2020-03-18',265586,0,2306.9,'PO07673','blue/Prov','60','GRV8399','Purchase Order','26382.0001')
,   ('AP','2020-03-18',265607,0,2306.9,'PO07673','blue/Prov','60','GRV8455','Purchase Order','26391.0001')
,   ('GL','2020-03-18',877518,0,2306.9,'PO07673','blue/Prov','60','GRV8455','Purchase Order','26391.0001')
,   ('GL','2020-03-18',877530,2.57,0,'PO07673','60',60,'GRV8481','Accounts Payable','26391.0002')
,   ('GL','2020-03-18',877525,0,23008.37,'PO07673','60',60,'GRV8481','Purchase Order','26391.0002')
,   ('AP','2020-03-18',265608,0,23008.37,'PO07673','60',60,'GRV8481','Purchase Order','26391.0002')
```

When I run this query:

```
select
rank() over (order by TxDate,AuditNumber) rnk
,   *
from    @table
```

I get the following Results:

[image: Current Results]

I'm trying to generate a new number according to each different `AuditNumber`, however it doesn't count from 1 to 3, but 1,3,5.

I've tried `partition by` & `row_number`, etc. but then I get only the number 1.

What am I missing?

My Expected Results:

[image: Expected Results]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DENSE_RANK`, which always advances the rank counter by 1 for each group of identically-valued records:

```
SELECT
    *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TxDate, AuditNumber) rnk
FROM @table;
```